# PjSip PJUSA2 unable to make Outgoing Call Android?

Tags: android, networking, sip, pjsip

```
MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);
CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
String number = "sip:123@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx";

try {
    call.makeCall(number, prm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    call.delete();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

currentCall = call;
showCallActivity();
```

I am Unable to make Call,I am registering Succesfully and reciveing incoming call succesfully but when i try to make outgoing call,call is not connected in PJSUA2.

Comment: What is error messages?

Comment: i am facing the same issue @Devendra did you find any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

test once with VPN.
Sometimes ISP,s alters sip header